# php Mockery throwing unexpected "must implement interface" exception when function method is typehinted

Tags: php, mockery

I'm using Mockery to unit test an admittedly edge case. It's failing and I don't think it should fail, so there could be a bug within Mockery.

Consider an object that has a method. The method has an argument signature where the first argument is typehinted and defaults to null. The second argument does not have a default.

When the method is called on the object with null as first argument, it works fine. When the method is called on a Mocked object with null as the first argument, it fails.

Please see sample code here: https://gist.github.com/awei01/9278119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug. References:

- https://github.com/padraic/mockery/pull/292
- https://github.com/davedevelopment/mockery/commit/e0fee6c08958ab6f35e8006aa761fc2d818f116c